# How to enable horizontal scrollbar to pop when ‘nowrap’ is set in Vim?

Tags: vim

Can someone help me to find a solution for the following inconvenience? I would like horizontal scrollbar to appear whenever I set the `nowrap` option, and vice versa when I set it back to `wrap`.

Currently I use these settings individually to ease my work:

```
nnoremap <silent> <F3> :if &guioptions=~#'b'<Bar>set guioptions-=b<Bar>else<Bar>set guioptions+=b<Bar>endif<CR>
map <F2> :set nowrap! <CR>
```

Is there a way to toggle them both at the same time, in concordance?

Answer (score 43):

Let us construct a single command for switching both options accordingly
at once.  First of all, it should toggle the `wrap` option anyway:

```
:set wrap!
```

Then, `guioptions` should be changed depending on whether wrapping is
enabled at the moment of command's execution.  If text is wrapped, the
bottom scrollbar should be shown in preparation for `wrap` to be
disabled:

```
:set guioptions+=b
```

Alternatively, if text wrapping is turned off, it should hide the bottom
scrollbar:

```
:set guioptions-=b
```

In order to make one command out of the above three, we can use the
expression mapping

```
:nnoremap <silent><expr> <f2> ':set wrap! go'..'-+'[&wrap].."=b\r"
```

which turns into the sequence of keystrokes

> `:set wrap! go+=b`<kbd>Enter</kbd>

when the `wrap` option is set (and evaluates to one), or into

> `:set wrap! go-=b`<kbd>Enter</kbd>

otherwise (when `&wrap` evaluates to zero).

Comment: @ib. What would be the code using inoremap? Actually I use a function for it: `function! Wrap() if &wrap set nowrap set guioptions+=b else set wrap set guioptions-=b endif endfunction` and the mapping `inoremap <silent> <F2> <ESC>:call Wrap()<CR>a`

Comment: @Remonn: For Insert mode, the mapping would be as follows.
`:inoremap <silent><expr> <f2> "\<C-O>:set wrap! go".'-+'[&wrap]."=b\r"`.
It's more convenient to use Ctrl+O to leave Insert mode temporarily for one command (and return back immediately after its execution) than to manually exit to Normal mode with Esc and then reenter Insert mode afterwards with the `i` or `a` Normal-mode commands. Furthermore, the former approach leaves the cursor position in tact while the latter one might change it in some cases.

Comment: which version of vim is this working on? I tried it on Vim 7.4 and it only wrap and unwrap text - the scrollbar never shows up -- is there some extra setup needed for this to work?

Comment: @serup: The question pertains GVim, the graphical variant of Vim (hence `guioptions`); instances of Vim run in terminal ignore the `guioptions` settings.